# Добавление пользователя в базу, после оплаты

Tags: python, aiogram

как прибавлять баланс пользователю в телеграм боте после оплаты?

```
    if t in 'paid':
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,  f'✅ Поздравляем! Баланс был пополнен, ваш баланс{balance} \n\n')

    print("gotovo")
else:
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'✅Счет не был пополнен, ваш баланс {balance}')
    print("no")
```

Comment: База данных уже создана, есть колонки, balance и остальные. Не могу сформировать правильный запрос с добавлением в базу данных

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.